# How to set zsh terminal's error message language to English?

Tags: zsh

I installed zsh but found the error message is Chinese, which is the local machine's language. I want to set it to English.

I edited my ~/.zshrc file and set

```
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

.
After reboot my zsh by `source ~/.zshrc` and use command `locale`, the output is:

```
➜  Documents locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=zh_CN:zh
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

While  the error message is not changed, it's still Chinese, like this:

```
zsh: 是一个目录: /usr/share/man/
```

I am confused, how to set my error message and output of zsh to English?

Comment: You can see `LANGUAGE=zh_CN:zh`, which is probably where the Chinese is coming from.

Comment: Run `update-locale LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8`.